# Como trazer uma lista de item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso  trazer uma lista de `ITEMS`, com apenas o id do Pedido. A forma que eu faço é essa, mas ele me traz apenas um Item, quero poder trazer todos os item que tenho, com o ID do pedido.

```
var listaItems = new ItemRepositorio().BuscarTodos().FirstOrDefault(c => c.PedidoId == Id);
```

Comment: Amigo no seu `ItemRepositorio()` não tem um método para fazer isso! Qual é o código do seu `ItemRepositorio()` e as classes de Entidade! melhore a sua pergunta, porque talvez esteja fazendo uso indevido desse código!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public List<ClasseUsada> FindAll(int pedidoId)
    {
        using (Conexao con = new Conexao())
        {
            return con.Tabela.Where(x=>x.Pedidoid.equals(pedidoid)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Boa tarde segue código com esse codigo retorna todos que tenham id passado

Answer (score 0):

Basta trocar seu FirstOrDefault por Where.

O FirstOrDefault retornar o primeiro objeto estabelecendo ou não uma condição, já o Where retornar todos os objetos encontrados na condição.

Comment: Valeu mesmo, de tanto bater cabeça, tinha nem prestado atenção no Where. Obrigado !!